# How to JOIN (alternative to Mapping) multiple tables in Spring Webflux (IntelliJ) (Postgres database)?

Tags: join, intellij-idea, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

**How to Join multiple tables in Spring WebFlux for Relational Database?**

In Spring Boot, in order to join two tables, we can perform different mappings (@OneToOne, @ManyToOne, @OneToMany). One example is shown below for mapping between doctor and patient.

Doctor Class (Entity)

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Doctor {
    @Id
    private int did;
    private String dname;
    private String specs;
}
```

Patient Class (Entity)

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Patient {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Doctor.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Id_Fk")
    private Doctor doctor;
}
```

For Spring Webflux, I have created two tables (postgresSQL) shown below, their respective repositories, a handler and a router in IntelliJ. **How to code the above in Spring Webflux as we can't use @Entity or any mapping annotations there?**

Doctor Table

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Doctor {
    @Id
    private int did;
    private String dname;
    private String specs;
}
```

Patient Table

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Patient {
    @Id
    private int pid;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Comment: You have to do as old school. In Patient should have the property int doctorId and save first the doctor and then the patient.

Comment: I did that...but now the problem is when I need to perform JOIN operation based on the common column of the two tables in webflux by using @Query, I mention it in one of the respective table repository. Then, it only shows the entry of that table and no column of the other.

Comment: To be more specific, I added a foreign key in doctor table referring to primary key of Patient Table. 
In the doctor repository, I added a @Query to perform JOIN between two tables. However, when I run in the localhost, it shows only the entry of doctor and none of patient.

Comment: @Query("select doctor.*, patient.id as Pat_Id, patient.name as Pat_Name, patient.age as Pat_Age from Doctor doctor join Patient patient on patient.id = doctor.pid ")
    public Flux<Doctor> findAlldetails();

Comment: That should be because the repository doesn't know where set the Patient properties (patient.name patient.age) because Doctor doesn't have that properties, and the method has to return a Doctor. May you need to create a new class to keep all that properties together, or make 2 calls, in order to get a Doctorn and a Patient

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks